# Ubuntu won't boot, only displays GRUB terminal

Tags: 11.04, grub2

I have a problem with Ubuntu 11.04. I've installed Ubuntu 11.04 from Windows, it worked fine for days, but today it won't boot.

When I start the machine, GRUB loads. There is the Windows 7 loader, I select Ubuntu from there and after that, I should see the Ubuntu GRUB menu, where I'd select the mode to boot Ubuntu. However, I can't see that any more. I directly get to a GRUB terminal.

Can anyone help me with this? How would I recover my data or reset the boot loader?

Comment: what do you get in terminal ?? Can you paste the screenshot ?

Comment: it is a terminal when i try to boot. How can I make a screen shot then. Anyway is empty. "GRUB>";

Comment: seems like a fielsystem error you will need to boot from live usb and check your filesystem with a command `fsck` or from `gparted` or `disk utility`

Comment: There should be some error message before the grub prompt.  You can take a picture of the screen with a cell phone or camera and upload that to photobucket or something.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot from LiveCD or USB.
2. Parted Magic and Ubuntu Live CD specifically.
3. Check if Ubuntu files are still there. If your Ubuntu partition is
   ok, maybe there's some problem with the Kernel. You may try to
   install a new one...